# How to display every other character in a string starting with the first character in NASM assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I am very new to NASM assembly programming find it very confusing, so I was wondering if I could ask for help in creating a NASM program which displays every other character in a preset string (starting with the first character)?

> Input: helloworld
>
> Output: hlool

I know that in higher programming languages like C, you would need to create a variable index = 0, and then increment the value of the index by 2 in order to skip the next character.

```
for (int index = 0; index < len; index +=2){
printf("%c", str[index]); 
}
```

But I am quite lost trying to figure out how to translate this logic into NASM assembly language. Thank you very much in advanced for any help regarding this!

Comment: Do you know how to display a single character in assembly?

Comment: No, I'm unfortunately not yet familiar with printing a single character within a string in assembly just yet :(

Comment: @ktrnln In your previous exercises, how did you produce any sort of output?

Comment: [NASM Print one Character at a Time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8426491) shows how to do that with Linux 32-bit system calls.  Increment by 2 and use a loop counter in a different register instead of looking for a terminating `0` like that code is doing.  (Assuming you want to do this the inefficient way, making one system call per byte, instead of looping through a buffer and copying to set up for one `write` call.)

Comment: You're better off allocating memory for a new string and copying every other character to that memory and printing it.